# Como sobrescrever uma variável de forma dinâmica ao fazer um laço em uma query?

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma variável `$x = 0` e a `$y = 10` na seguinte query:

```
select * from tabela limit 10 offset 0
```

Essa query faz um laço, mais precisaria que nesse laço o valor do `offset` incrementasse `+10` a cada laço até chegar na ultima linha da query para parar o laço, alguém sabe como eu posso esta fazendo isso:

Meu código esta assim:

```
$conexão = mysql_connect('localhost','root','password');
$db = mysql_select_db}('banco');


//essa query é pra fazer o loop da segunda query
$sql = "select * from tabela";
$query = mysql_query($sql);

$rows = mysql_num_rows($query);

while($rows > 0){

   //define o limit
   $x = 0;

   //define o offset
   $y = 4;

  //essa query é que vai retornar a informação
$sql = "select * from limit $y offset $x";

   $query = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query){

  resultado da segunda query;
}

}
```

Precisaria fazer isso porque tenho um tabela de 5 mil linhas, preciso pegar todas as linhas só que parcelado de 100 em 100 linhas, o laço só pega da primeira linha até o limit que é 10 no exemplo, o que eu estou tentando fazer nesse laço:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não sei se entendi direito o problema, mas não é só somar o quanto deseja incrementar de offset na variável $y no final do primeiro while?

Comment: Fica a sugestão de esclarecer todos os detalhes na pergunta anterior. Fique à vontade para fazer perguntas separadas sobre problemas separados, mas procure resolver cada questão.

Comment: @Bacco acredito que nenhum, mas no problema anterior ele não tinha conseguido explicar o problema muito bem e ninguém tinha respondido de acordo. Acredito que já respondi ele na pergunta original de forma aceitável. E acho que a pergunta aqui pode ser marcada como duplicata.

Comment: @tayllan eu reli as duas, aí acabei fechando quando editei o comentário anterior. Se a sua resposta não resolveu o problema dele, seria o caso dele editar aquela mesmo e explicar melhor a questão. Ambas as "versões" tão um pouco confusas. Na verdade eu tou achando que a anterior já é duplicata, mas vou esperar o Danilo esclarecer melhor aquela pra vermos como ajudar melhor.